# How to save an igraph object

Tags: r, igraph

I have a problem writing my data frame to csv file.

g looks like this

```
> g
IGRAPH c32bbbf UN-- 12 12 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from c32bbbf (vertex names):
 [1] 2 --3  3 --1  4 --5  5 --6  4 --6  6 --7  6 --8  6 --9  9 --8  10--11 11--12 10--12
```

None of folowing code works

```
write.table(g,  file = "filename.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv2(membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)), "name.csv" , row.names = FALSE)
write.table(membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)),  file = "name.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```

It shows this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"membership"’ to a data.frame
```

How can I write g or membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)) into a .csv file?
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `g` is not a data.frame but an `igraph` object; if you want to save that you could either use `.RData` or `.rds` files, see `save` and `saveRDS` respectively

Comment: Could you show me how the code should look like please? For storing g and membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)? It needs to be stored to .csv format.

Comment: In general, a graph can't be written as a csv file, since it is not a tabular data structure. If you want a graph saved in a plain text format you could do `write_graph(g,  file = "filename.txt", format = "edgelist")` and read it back into R with `read_graph("filename.txt", format = "edgelist")`. These are both functions in the `igraph` package and are well documented in the help files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write.table` and `write.csv` require that the input be a tabular data (data.frame/matrix/etc.). Your object `g` is an igraph object. As others have mentioned, one option is to use igraph's `write_graph()` [function](https://igraph.org/r/doc/write_graph.html), that will write the graph to a text file and allows different formats for how the data is written.

Another option would be to use igraph's `as_long_data_frame` [function](https://igraph.org/r/doc/as_long_data_frame.html) to convert your graph object to a dataframe, which can then be written to a csv file using `write.csv`. However, this requires that the vertices be named.

For example:

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_ring(10)

# add names to vertices
vertex_attr(g) <- list(name = LETTERS[1:10])    
vertex_attr(g, "label") <- V(g)$name

as_long_data_frame(g)    

#>  from to from_name from_label to_name to_label
#>     1  2         A          A       B        B
#>     2  3         B          B       C        C
#>     3  4         C          C       D        D
#>     4  5         D          D       E        E
#>     5  6         E          E       F        F
#>     6  7         F          F       G        G
#>     7  8         G          G       H        H
#>     8  9         H          H       I        I
#>     9 10         I          I       J        J
#>     1 10         A          A       J        J
```

Comment: Isolated vertices will be lost though.

Answer (score 1):

Use igraph's `write_graph()` function. Check the documentation for available formats.